# How to writes the log on the screen during shutdown and startup (after grub)

Tags: systemd, logs, startup, shutdown, reboot

As we know, when we startup the system (after grub) and when we shutdown the system, many logs will be printed on screen.

I know that the kernel would write some logs of the kernel. But how about the others? Who writes them?

As I know, Ubuntu uses `systemd` and there are some logs from `systemd`. I want to know if it is possible that I could create a service of `systemd`, which can write some logs on screen while starting up and shutting down?

Comment: To me at least it is unclear what your intentions are with "creating a service of **systemd**. Yes, the kernel, systemd and other applications will write to the screen during the boot process.

Comment: You might be looking at logs written by [Plymouth](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/), which is a boot splash manager in modern Linux distributions.

Comment: @Tommiie   I simply want to know how to write a log message with my own service or process while startup and shutdown.

Comment: @Yves : that is a completely different question than “who writes to the screen during startup”

Answer (score 0):

Can analyze the reboot system call source code, maybe the answer is there.
PATH: linux-4.4.1/kernel/reboot.c

```
280 SYSCALL_DEFINE4(reboot, int, magic1, int, magic2, unsigned int, cmd,
281                 void __user *, arg)
282 {
        ....
315         switch (cmd) {
316         case LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART:
        ....
333         case LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF:
334                 kernel_power_off();
335                 do_exit(0);
336                 break;
        ....


257 void kernel_power_off(void)
258 {
259         kernel_shutdown_prepare(SYSTEM_POWER_OFF);
260         if (pm_power_off_prepare)
261                 pm_power_off_prepare();
262         migrate_to_reboot_cpu();
263         syscore_shutdown();
264         pr_emerg("Power down\n");
265         kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_POWEROFF);
266         machine_power_off();
267 }
```

Comment: Before kernel doing its shutdown, we can see many log have been printed on the screen. So this shouldn't have business with the kernel.

Comment: The kernel outputs some information before the real shutdown.
265         kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_POWEROFF);
266         machine_power_off();